# border-radius use in IE (All Version)

Tags: html, css

How to use border-radius in IE.(All Browsers)

because firefox,chrome support border-radius but how to use for IE?

Comment: at least IE 10 supports border-radius, so you should be more specific, don't include all the versions here.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: the border-radius feature is not something really important, it's just some kind of UI enhancement, so for other versions, we simply just accept the sharp square angles. I think many people will switch to the latest version soon.

Comment: You can use a JS polyfill such as [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) for IE8 retro-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

you need try this:

```
.my-block {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
  border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
  /* Для плохих IE */
  behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /*IE border-radius */
}
```

Fortunately, IE can be quite beautiful to win his own means. One of my favorite solutions using VML and behaviour - curved-corner. To use merge border-radius.htc, we add next to CSS and use the following code: Spent time